# Weil pairing exact sequence split for an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with a p-torsion point $P$ lying in $E(\mathbb{Q})$, where $p$ is a prime number. Let $e(\ ,\ )$ denote the Weil pairing.

Choose a point $Q$ such that $P, Q$ consist of a basis of $E[p]$, then we have the exact sequence $0\rightarrow \text{ker}f \hookrightarrow E[p]\xrightarrow{f}  \mu_p\rightarrow 0$, where $f$ is the map $S\rightarrow e(S,P)$, and it is easy to know $\text{ker}f=\{\mathbb{Z}P\}$.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(E[p])$, so $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ acts on $E[p]$ by $g(P)=P, g(Q)=xP+yQ$ for two integers $x, y$ and $p\nmid y$.

$\textbf{So the question is that}$ how to prove the short exact sequence metioned above splits if and only if $x=0$.

This is very important for me to prove Mazur's theorem which says that the torsion is not more than 13.

Thanks !

Comment: I don't get it. The short exact sequence does not depend on the automorphism $g$, so what exactly is going on. Also, don't we always have $E[p]\cong C_p\times C_p$, so the sequence always splits (as a sequence of abelian groups)?

Comment: Dear@JyrkiLahtonen, please see [this thesis](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/schwartz/thesis.pdf), the proof in lemma 5.2 on page 26.

Comment: Ok. It says there that we are looking at a short exact sequence *of $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$-modules.* That is what I was wondering about. As a short exact sequence *of abelian groups* it always splits.

Comment: Anyway, because $P\in E(\Bbb{Q})$, it spans a trivial $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$-module. Splitting as a module does, indeed, mean that $x=0$ *for all $g\in Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$.* In other words, $E[p]$ has a complementary submodule, where $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$ acts the same way it does on $\mu_p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Sorry, but if the sequence splits, how to see $x=0$? If the sequence splits, then there exists a Galois invariant map $h: E[p] \rightarrow \text{ker}f$ such that $h(P)=P$. If we assume $h(Q)=nP$, then $h(g(Q))=g(h(Q))$, then $xP+nyP=nP$, so $p | x+ny-n$, but how to see $x=0$ ? Can you give your solution as an answer ? Thanks !

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  I may know what you mean. If this sequence splits, then $E[m]=\text{ker}f\bigoplus M$, so $M$ is consisted of $\mathbb{Z}Q$, but $M$ is a Galois submodule, so $g(M)\subseteq M$, so $x=0$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. That is a simple way to think about it. Feel free to post is as an answer. If somebody who really understands this shows up, you then get feedback from the directly.